# Eliminar extraño espacio en blanco a la derecha y scroll horizontal

Tags: css

lo que pasa es que al diseñar una web, en el espacio derecho me aparece un raro espacio en blanco, me aparece un scroll horizontal y no encuentro el motivo.
Acá el código
https://codepen.io/cris123m/pen/dyYrKdo

Answer (score 0):

Hay una imagen flotando y animada con la clase "anim-2". En el código no agregaste la imagen, no te puedo ayudar modificando exactamente los valores, porque no se cuál sea tu caso en específico.

El width de `.anim-2` está agregado como 70%, cambialo a tu conveniencia, porque está superando el tamaño del documento por la posición absoluta.